# 3306ポートが既に使われていてdocker runできない

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker

現在、dockerを利用するアプリケーションとdockerを外したアプリケーションを混在したシステムを開発しています。dbはmysqlを利用していて、それはdockerを利用しています。
ところが、dockerを利用していないものが存在しているせいか、dockerでmysqlをビルドランしようとすると、次のエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
Starting *****-db ... 
Starting *****-db ... error

ERROR: for *****-db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ff-fdsvr-db (*****): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint *****-db (*****): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Makefile:25: ターゲット 'migration' のレシピで失敗しました
make: *** [migration] エラー 1
```

恐らく、現在3306ポートを利用しているプロセスをstopまたはkillすればいいのだと思いますが、`ss -antu`コマンドで調べても、次のようにどのプロセスが使用しているのかわかりません。

```
tcp    LISTEN     0      80     127.0.0.1:3306                  *:*
```

この場合、どうしたら解決できるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。
環境は、以下のとおりです。

OS:ubuntu16.04
mysql:5.7
python:3.6

Comment: root 権限で `ss -antup` を実行すると(`p` オプションを追加)、ポートを使用しているプロセス名やプロセスIDを表示してくれますよ。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。さっそく試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

`lsof`コマンドの`-i`オプションで`:ポート番号`を指定して実行すると、該当のポートを使用しているプロセスがもしあればコマンド名やプロセスIDが表示されます。

```
$ lsof -i :3306
```