# Docker for windowsをアップデートしたらでコンテナが起動しなくなりました

Tags: docker

先日Docker for windowsの更新通知が表示されたので、そのまま更新しました。
記憶があいまいですが、その後1度はコンテナを起動できたと思います。
昨日PCを起動して、コンテナを起動しようとしたら以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
ERROR: for testdb  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint testdb (89219210c53c9d5a9bf33de3e5a1601e7ca2dabc5c888db0fc4cc27641a10d4a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:13306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

ネットで調べて、docker for windowsを再起動したら直るという記事をみつけて試しましたがなおりませんでした。
仕方なくdocker for windowsをアンインストールして再度インストールしました。
それで昨日はコンテナを起動することができました。
ですが、今朝になりまた同様のエラーが表示されコンテナを起動できなくなりました。
どなたか解決方法がわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Comment: OSは違いますが関連質問 - [3306ポートが既に使われていてdocker runできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/50813)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すいません、以下の記事にある方法で解決しました。
https://qiita.com/masaoops/items/e79157ec89cd991ef8d2

実行中のコンテナをすべて停止して以下のコマンドをたたいてOS再起動しました。

```
docker system prune -f
```

古いコンテナやらネットワークやらがportをつかみっぱなしにしていたとかですかね...

[追記]
結局、再発しました。
2.1.0.0から2.0.0.3に戻しました。